# sqlsntax and odbc code wont insert?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

can anyone help me with this it doesnt seem to insert anything?

```
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x;");
        cn.Open();

    try
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPostings (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + Table1 + "')", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;

    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

}

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `gymwebsite`.`User`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gymwebsite`.`User` (

  `UserID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `Email` VARCHAR(245) NULL ,

  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `SecondName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `DOB` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,

  `Location` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `Aboutme` VARCHAR(245) NULL ,

  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;





-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `gymwebsite`.`Pictures`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gymwebsite`.`Pictures` (

  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,

  `picturepath` VARCHAR(245) NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) ,

  INDEX `fk_Pictures_Userinfo1` (`UserID` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_Pictures_Userinfo1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID` )

    REFERENCES `gymwebsite`.`User` (`UserID` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;





-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `gymwebsite`.`WallPostings`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gymwebsite`.`WallPostings` (

  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,

  `Wallpostings` MEDIUMTEXT  NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) ,

  INDEX `fk_WallPostings_Userinfo1` (`UserID` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_WallPostings_Userinfo1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID` )

    REFERENCES `gymwebsite`.`User` (`UserID` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE WallPostings`?

Comment: And add a Try Catch block where you output any exceptions that you may be getting.

Comment: done, no error on vs side with try catch. Can only think i have my syntax wrong but i doudt it. Maybe its the ASP Table control thats not being picked up the data thats inside my table (unformated) is html content (have to save that content to the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that UserID would be an integer, and you've got this part in your query:

```
('UserID="+theUserId+"','"+Table1+"')
```

Try this one instead:

```
("+theUserId+",'"+Table1+"')
```

**EDIT:** Is UserID a primary key inside WallPostings table? That means you can only have one row per UserID. This is probably not what you had in mind, try deleting the primary key/try a query with a UserId that doesn't have any posts.

Comment: nope that doesnt work either? hmmm what on earth is going wrong

Comment: @Garrith: you might also want to add a Try block and catch some SQL exceptions. Additionally you would probably want to close your connection when finished.

Comment: Yes it is a primary key, how to I relate it to the user table? the options are PK(PriKey) NN (not null) then ones I dont know what they are UQ, BIN, UN, ZF and Auto Increment. Have no clue how to relate it to the user table? without the primary key

Comment: ok I dropped the primary key to see if I could insert it still nothing? Defo sure its the table1 thats not working.

Comment: ok nope tryed just inserting with actual values cant seem to insert anything to the table?

Comment: yet i can insert into the user table just fine?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much data, but it seems you are trying to insert a string like `UserID=3` into an integer `UserID` field.

Answer (score 1):

What/Where is the variable Table1 in your code?

Comment: its not the table tested with textbox still cant insert anything

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, for some reason when jquery is bound to a button in this instance button1 it invalidates the control. Seems you cant have buttons doing multiple things.